# Casting datatypes with the same number of bytes without reallocation and copying in C++?

Tags: c++, casting

Let's say I have a `char a;` variable in C++, and I want to make it an `unsigned char`. Both datatype contains exactly one byte; the byte will stay the same when we do casting, so we are not really doing anything to the bytes.

However, I cannot change the type of variable `a`. If I declare a new variable `unsigned char b = (unsigned char) a;`, I am allocating memory for `b` (and using lots of memory if I have lots of such variables to cast), and I am doing unnecessary copying. How can I change the type of `a` without such copying?

Secondly, if I have `std::vector<char> v;` and I wish to cast it to `std::vector<unsigned char>`, what's the most efficient way to do so (without copying)? (Imagine a situation when you have `char` but some function takes `unsigned char` as its input.)

Comment: Generally speaking, when you feel the need to do a C-style casting like that, you should take that as a sign you're doing something wrong. What is the use-case? What problem is the cast supposed to solve?

Comment: You are allowed to just `reinterpret_cast` a `char*` to `unsigned char*` and access the characters through that. So there is no issue for this specific case.

Comment: _"if I have `std::vector<char> v;` and I wish to cast it to `std::vector<unsigned char>`, what's the most efficient way to do so (without copying)?_" - I suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62505019/assign-stdvectorstdbyte-to-stdvectorchar-without-copying-memory/62505567#62505567) to a similar question

Comment: If you need to pass a `vector<char>` as a parameter to `void foo(vector<unsigned char>&)` the code probably has a design flaw.

Comment: Why not have your vector be `unsigned char` in the first place?

Comment: @Eljay See my comment at the end of the qiestion - sometimes one just cannot change the definition of every function (e.g. functions in a library).

Comment: That's why it's important to have good function interface from the very beginning. You can't cast `std::vector<A>` into `std::vector<B>` for distinct types `A` and `B`.

Comment: Does the library functions really take a `std::vector<unsigned char>` as argument? Not iterators? Not a `unsigned char*` + length?

Comment: *sometimes one just cannot change the definition of every function*  In those cases, one cannot avoid copying and transforming the data.